# How to connect to db4free database using 'mysql' command from the terminal

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am running MySQL 5.5 on Ubuntu 14.04. I can open and work with local databases using `mysql` in the terminal. I can also run phpMyAdmin and access the database on db4free.net on the browser. However i would like to know how to achieve the same (access the db4free DB) from the terminal using `mysql` command.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this command

```
mysql -u <username> -p -h db4free.net
```

Comment: What if I am behind a proxy. Is there a way to let `mysql` use proxy?

Comment: @blumonkey: depends on the proxy: most: yes, some: no

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the server allows remote access, from [Mysql.com: MySQL ::   MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: 4.2.2 Connecting to the MySQL Server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html), run this command:

```
mysql --host=<mysql_server_ip_address> --user=<mysql_username> --password <mysql_database_name>
```

If the server doesn't use the default `MySQL` port (`3306`), append the `--port` argument to the command:

```
mysql --host=<mysql_server_ip_address> --port=<mysql_server_port> --user=<mysql_username> --password <mysql_database_name>
```

Then enter your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

On a side note, you could even append the password directly to the command by using `--password=<mysql_password>` instead of `--password`, altough users on your system would be able to see it by running `ps auxw`, so see for yourself which method suits the most.